# Retrieving a JSON result

Tags: javascript, php, json

Hi I have used a code snippet from a tutorial for a chat application all of its scripts are working fine but after I tweak it to make the code work based on my requirements almost all of the scripts are working except for retrieving the conversation

The error I'm having is it doesn't retrieve the conversation from my database

here is the modified script

```
 //Create the JSON response.
$json = '{"messages": {';
//Check to ensure the user is in a chat room.
if(!isset($_GET['chat'])) {

    $json .= '"message":[ {';
    $json .= '"id":  "0",
                "user": "Admin",
                "text": "You are not currently in a chat session.  &lt;a href=""&gt;Enter a chat session here&lt;/a&gt;",
                "time": "' . date('h:i') . '"
            }]';
} else {
    $con3 = new PDO("mysql:host=". db_host .";dbname=db", db_username , db_password);
    $con3->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

    $con4 = new PDO("mysql:host=". db_host .";dbname=chat_db", db_username , db_password);
    $con4->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    $sql5 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :rid LIMIT 1";
    $stmt6=$con4->prepare($sql5);
    $stmt6->bindValue( 'rid',$_POST['rid'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt6->execute();
        foreach($stmt6->fetchAll()as $res)
            {
                $usern = $res['username'];
                $user_lvl = $res['ulvl'];
            }

    $comb = $usern . $_POST['name'];

      //Validation if msgid exists before creating a new table on the 2nd database
      $sql6="SELECT msgid FROM thread WHERE combination1=:msgids OR combination2=:submsgids LIMIT 1";
      $msg_id = $con4->prepare($sql6);
      $msg_id->bindParam(':msgids', $comb, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $msg_id->bindParam(':submsgids', $comb, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $msg_id->execute();
      $msgd = $msg_id->fetchColumn();
      $tbpre = $msgd . "chat_conversation";
    $sql7 = "SELECT msgid, message_content, username , message_time FROM $tblpre WHERE msgid=:chat";

    $stmt7=$con3->prepare($sql7);
    $stmt7->bindValue( ':chat', $msgd, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt7->execute();

    $message_query = $stmt7;
    //Loop through each message and create an XML message node for each.
    if(count($message_query) > 0) {
        $json .= '"message":[ ';    
        while($message_array = $stmt7->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $json .= '{';
            $json .= '"id":  "' . $message_array['msgid'] . '",
                        "user": "' . htmlspecialchars($message_array['username']) . '",
                        "text": "' . htmlspecialchars($message_array['message_content']) . '",
                        "time": "' . $message_array['message_time'] . '"
                    },';
        }
        $json .= ']';
    } else {
        //Send an empty message to avoid a Javascript error when we check for message lenght in the loop.
        $json .= '"message":[]';
    }

}

//Close our response

$json .= '}}';
echo $json;
```

Here is the code for calling this script

```
    //Gets the current messages from the server
        function getChatText() {
            if (receiveReq.readyState == 4 || receiveReq.readyState == 0) {
                receiveReq.open("GET", 'includes/getChat.php?chat='+uid+'&last=' + lastMessage, true);
                receiveReq.onreadystatechange = handleReceiveChat; 
                receiveReq.send(null);
            }           
        }
        function sendChatText() {

            if (sendReq.readyState == 4 || sendReq.readyState == 0) {
                sendReq.open("POST", 'includes/getChat.php?last=' + lastMessage, true);
                sendReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                sendReq.onreadystatechange = handleSendChat; 
                var param = 'message=' + document.getElementById('txtA').value;
                param += '&name='+user;
                param += '&uid='+uid;
                param += '&rid='+document.getElementById('trg').value;
                sendReq.send(param);
                document.getElementById('txtA').value = '';
            }                           
        }
    //When our message has been sent, update our page.
        function handleSendChat() {
            //Clear out the existing timer so we don't have 
            //multiple timer instances running.
            clearInterval(mTimer);
            getChatText();

        }
        function handleReceiveChat() {
            if (receiveReq.readyState == 4) {
                //Get a reference to our chat container div for easy access
                var chat_div = document.getElementById('clog');


                var response = eval("(" + receiveReq.responseText + ")");
                for(i=0;i < response.messages.message.length; i++) {
                    chat_div.innerHTML += response.messages.message[i].user;
                    chat_div.innerHTML += '&nbsp;&nbsp;<font class="chat_time">' +  response.messages.message[i].time + '</font><br />';
                    chat_div.innerHTML += response.messages.message[i].text + '<br />';
                    chat_div.scrollTop = chat_div.scrollHeight;
                    lastMessage = response.messages.message[i].id;
                }
                mTimer = setTimeout('getChatText();',20000); //Refresh our chat in 2 seconds
            }
        }
```

Am I missing something here or doing something wrong?

Comment: You should not generate json manually. Just generate an array / object and use `json_encode()`.

Comment: You're not going to give us ANY info about what's wrong, what errors you see, what part of the code is giving you the wrong result?  Seriously, no hints whatsoever?  Sorry, but I don't even attempt to help my officemate with that little information.

Comment: Hi master jeroen I'm quite new on JSON so do you have any recommended site on which I could use as a reference for json_encode()?

Comment: @user256009 **Result #1 in Google:** [The documentation for `json_encode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). Seriously. At least try. The PHP documentation should be the first place you go for answers to this sort of thing.

Comment: Master @jfriend00 my problem is it doesn't return any result from the database.. I've tried using firebug to see if my script is working and yes its working fine and doesn't have any errors

Comment: Mr @tadman thanks and sorry I'm new to programming so I'm not that familiar yet on where to go

Comment: Google's (or your favourite search engine) usually a good place to start. The [PHP site](http://php.net/) is even better.

Comment: Could be a silly question, but: is data on the database? Have you tried run the queries directly against your database?

Comment: @jloria yes I tried to display my data on a php driven without any json and javascript on it

Comment: @user256009 Ok, in the script you show, I see constants db_host, db_username, etc, but I don't see any define or require db config file. Are you sure that these constants have the right values?

Comment: This is a classic debugging scenario. You should track through the code and keep an eye on the values that get passed from point to point. If you don't have a full debugging environment, sometimes just `var_dump`ing your PHP objects and `console.log`ging your JS objects at each point along the way until you find what's missing really is the simplest approach.

Answer (score 1):

You should rewrite using `json_encode`:

```
$messages = array();
//Check to ensure the user is in a chat room.
if(!isset($_GET['chat'])) {
    $message_object = (object) array(
        "id"=>"0",
        "user"=>"Admin",
        "text"=>"You are not currently in a chat session.  &lt;a href=\"\"&gt;Enter a chat session here&lt;/a&gt;",
        "time"=>date('h:i')
    );
    $messages[] = (object) array("message"=>$message_object);
} else {
    $con3 = new PDO("mysql:host=". db_host .";dbname=db", db_username , db_password);
    $con3->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

    $con4 = new PDO("mysql:host=". db_host .";dbname=chat_db", db_username , db_password);
    $con4->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    $sql5 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :rid LIMIT 1";
    $stmt6=$con4->prepare($sql5);
    $stmt6->bindValue( 'rid',$_POST['rid'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt6->execute();
        foreach($stmt6->fetchAll()as $res)
            {
                $usern = $res['username'];
                $user_lvl = $res['ulvl'];
            }

    $comb = $usern . $_POST['name'];

    //Validation if msgid exists before creating a new table on the 2nd database
    $sql6="SELECT msgid FROM thread WHERE combination1=:msgids OR combination2=:submsgids LIMIT 1";
    $msg_id = $con4->prepare($sql6);
    $msg_id->bindParam(':msgids', $comb, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $msg_id->bindParam(':submsgids', $comb, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $msg_id->execute();
    $msgd = $msg_id->fetchColumn();
    $tbpre = $msgd . "chat_conversation";
    $sql7 = "SELECT msgid, message_content, username , message_time FROM $tblpre WHERE msgid=:chat";

    $stmt7=$con3->prepare($sql7);
    $stmt7->bindValue( ':chat', $msgd, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt7->execute();

    $message_query = $stmt7;
    //Loop through each message and create an XML message node for each.
    if(count($message_query) > 0) {
        $message_object = (object) array(
            "id"=>$message_array['msgid'],
            "user"=>htmlspecialchars($message_array['username']),
            "text"=>htmlspecialchars($message_array['message_content']),
            "time"=>$message_array['message_time'
        );
        $messages[] = (object) array("message"=>$message_object);
    } else {
        //Send an empty message to avoid a Javascript error when we check for message lenght in the loop.
        $messages[] = (object) array("message"=>array());
    }

}

//Close our response
$result = (object) array('messages'=>$messages);
$json = json_encode($result);
echo $json;
```